# Special characters in R with str_replace

Tags: r, special-characters, str-replace, stringr

I have a dataframe with accented characters in certain columns (for example Company), so they appear as special characters. I tried to replace them by the correspondant non accented letter. But for some of them, it fails and I don't know why.

```
> str <- Df$Company[334]
> str
[1] "Reseau de Transport d'Ã‰lectricite"
> str_replace(str, pattern = "Ã‰", replacement = "E")
[1] "Reseau de Transport d'Ã‰lectricite"
```

However,

```
> str <- "Reseau de Transport d'Ã‰lectricite"
> str
[1] "Reseau de Transport d'Ã‰lectricite"
> str_replace(str, pattern = "Ã‰", replacement = "E")
[1] "Reseau de Transport d'Electricite"
```

How can I fix that ? 
Normally, it's included in this code (which works for "e" and others) :

```
soll <- c("e", "e", "e", "c", "i", "i", "E")
ist <- c("Ã©", "Ã«", "ã¨", "Ã§", "Ã®", "Ã¯", "Ã‰")

for(i in 1:ncol(Df)){
  for(j in 1:length(soll)){
    Df[,i] %<>% str_replace_all(pattern = ist[j], replacement = soll[j])
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'd try to fix this upstream, when importing the data, i.e. using the correct encoding, if possible.

Comment: @ThomasK How can I change the encoding while importing the data?

Comment: Depends on what kind of file you are importing. If `.csv`, take a look at `readr::read_csv`. You can set the encoding within `locale`, and you can try to find out about the encoding of your file with `readr::guess_encoding`.